# display:inline-block how to position the div in same level

Tags: html, css

There are two divisions inside another div which is also wrapped by a div

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="content">
            Hello how are you<br/>   
            Hello how are you<br/>
            Hello how are you<br/>    
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#page1">PAge1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page1">PAge1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page1">PAge1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page1">PAge1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So one of the division contains some paragraphs which is mentioned above as hello how are you and another is horizontal menu

So here is my CSS Code

```
#wrap
{
    width: 100%; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align: center;
}

#content
{
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 30%;
}

#main
{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px; 
}

#main div div
{
    display: inline-block;
}

#nav
{
    margin-left: 30px;
}

ul
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#menu li
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

#menu li a
{
    text-decoration: none;   
    color: yellow;
}
```

Now the problem is why the horizontal menu is not in the same line of paragraph starts,

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedmusthafac/DW52N/15/

i want the both div to be start in same line without using **float:left**

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what do you have in mind by writting "same line", I'd suggest to use `vertical-align: top` or `vertical-align: bottom` for inline-block elements.

In your case, I'd add that property to `#content` and `#nav` element like this:

```
#content {
    ....
    vertical-align: top;
}

#nav{
    ....
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Here's update jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/DW52N/17/

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Thank you for the code, This is what i expected

Comment: @musthafa Amazing: This is the first question I see which has all its answers without any vote and at the same time the question itself has not got any. One question and four answers with zero votes! At least, you may accept this anwer as it seems that it is the one that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS :**

```
#wrap
{
    width: 100%; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align:center;

}
#content
{
    background-color:yellow;
    width:30%;
   vertical-align: top;
}

#main
{
    width:100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    background-color:red;
    padding:10px; 
}
#main div div
{
    display:inline-block;

}

#nav
{
    margin-left:30px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

ul
{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
#menu li
{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid yellow;
}
#menu li a
{
 text-decoration:none;   
    color:yellow;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="wrap">
    <div id="content">
        Hello how are you<br/>   
        Hello how are you<br/>    Hello how are you<br/>    
    </div>
        <div id="nav">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#page1">PAge1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page1">PAge1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page1">PAge1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page1">PAge1</a></li>
        </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check out this it will work.

**Add these properties to your ids**

```
#content {
    ....
    vertical-align: top;
}

#nav{
    ....
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to align the content vertically center.

`#content, #nav {
  vertical-align: middle;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#content, #nav {
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

or

```
#content, #nav {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```